# How do I get a youtube video's upload date using GeckoFX 60's evaluate script method?

Tags: c#, geckofx

The GeckoFX 60 browser I'm using in WPF has an evaluate script method that takes in javascript code (in a form of a string).

**What I did:**

1. Looked for a YouTube video to test my javascript code
2. Placing `document.getElementById('date').innerText` on the console gave me the information I needed
3. Went back to my WPF app and placed this:

(C#)

```
string videoDate = "";
using (Gecko.AutoJSContext js = new Gecko.AutoJSContext(YouTubeBrowser.Window))
{
    js.EvaluateScript("document.getElementById('date').innerText", out videoDate);
}
NewProject.VideoDate = DateTime.Parse(videoDate);
```

**Problem:**

It was catching an error so I placed a break before parsing the string and found out that the videoDate string is null

**What I expected:**

I expected it to return the `•Jan 30, 2008` the console showed when I entered the js code on the browser.

So far these lines of code are working for me (both on the console and my wpf app's GeckoBrowser) when getting other information from the YouTube video:

`js.EvaluateScript("document.title", out videoTitle);` = gets the Video Title

`js.EvaluateScript("document.URL", out videoId);` = gets the Video Url (which I then filter out to only get the video id in c#)

**A few more things I've tried that didn't work:**

A. Using GeckoElement and retrieving the browser's Document and its textContent

```
GeckoElement elem = YouTubeBrowser.Document.GetElementById("date");
videoDate = elem.textContent;
```

B. Using GeckoElement and retrieving the browser's DomDocument and its textContent

```
GeckoElement elem = YouTubeBrowser.DOMDocument.GetElementById("date");
videoDate = elem.textContent;
```

C. Changed innerText to textContent (based on another SO answer I saw that said firefox didn't understand innerText (which is weird since it worked on the console but I guess they added support for that later on) but rather uses textContent to retrieve the value)

```
string videoDate = "";
using (Gecko.AutoJSContext js = new Gecko.AutoJSContext(YouTubeBrowser.Window))
{
    js.EvaluateScript("document.getElementById('date').textContent", out videoDate);
}
NewProject.VideoDate = DateTime.Parse(videoDate);
```

Comment: Are you allowing enough time for the page to fully render (in case this value is added by Javascript)?

Comment: Currently, I'm performing the command (that does the method above) when I visually see the date below the video. But I'll take your comment as a starting point for further testing, I'll look for a document completed event of some sort and return the CanUse for the command so it only gets enabled after the document fully loads. Thank You and I'll report back asap.

Comment: I made two bools `IsDocumentCompleted`, `HasNavigated` and made sure that the command only returns true if both of those are true. Initially they're set to false, and are also set to false during a Navigating event. But every time I click the command, it still doesn't work (even if the document is completed as has navigated). I might be missing the correct event though but so far that was my progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with the dynamic DOM on YouTube.
While I could not retrieve the value by element Id I found the same information on another Tag by class name:

```
_gfxBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("watch-time-text")[0].TextContent
```

Returns: `"Published on Jan 25, 2019"`

Comment: Incredible! `DateTime videoDate = DateTime.Parse((YouTubeBrowser.Document.GetElementsByClassName("watch-time-text")[0].TextContent).Substring(13));` did the trick! Thank you so much, I didn't expect someone would still answer this, I already gave up and just proceeded to use DateTime.Now and manually changed the date.